# Understanding Source Peaks with Half-Wave Rectifier with Capacitive Filter

Tags: rectifier

We started going over simple rectifier circuits in my electronics lab yesterday. When I implemented this circuit I was a bit confused by the source signal on the oscilloscope:

[image: Circuit]

and the readout:

[image: Osc readout]

I believe the stunted peak of the wave has to do with the the source crossing the forward voltage of the diode and the capacitor starts charging and in this process, sinking the current from the source, essentially shorting it, never allowing the source to reach its peak.

That's probably wrong but it's the only thing that makes sense to me at the moment.

We used a 47 microFarad electrolytic cap and a 1k ohm resistor.

Comment: _"sinking the current from the source, essentially shorting it"_ - you are probably right. What was the source?

Comment: The source was a 10V peak-to-peak sine wave at 1kHz.

Comment: Eyeballing the scope trace it looks like the source voltage was 12Vpp, so how did 'shorting it' cause the voltage to _increase_ from 10Vpp to 12Vpp? Exactly what was generating the source voltage?

Comment: We were using an Agilent signal generator. I realize now that we were outputting 20 V peak-to-peak. I must have pressed 10V amplitude, although I made sure to press peak-to-peak and that signal generator has done that multiple times. Regardless, that is why it is 12 V peak to peak. It reduced from 20 to 12. Good catch!

Comment: _"We were using an Agilent signal generator."_- what output impedance was it set to? (eg. 50 Ohms, 600 Ohms). _"We used a 47 microFarad electrolytic cap and a 1k ohm resistor."_ - please verify that these were the actual values used (my simulation suggests resistance was ~18 Ohms if generator impedance was 50 Ohms). Also what diode did you use?